# How to delete last element in java.util.Set?

Tags: java, collections

I want to delete every last element of this set.

```java
Set<String> listOfSources = new TreeSet<String>();
for(Route route:listOfRoutes){
    Set<Stop> stops = routeStopsService.getStops(route);
    for(Stop stop:stops)
       listOfSources.add(stop.getStopName());
}
```

Here I want to remove the last element from `listOfSources`.

Comment: IMO of your code relies on an ordered set then it's inappropriate to declare the variable as a Set. Coding to an interface only makes sense if the implementation doesn't matter--in this case it does, and your code will fail if you use the accepted answer and you change the set's implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to cast back to TreeSet, as Set's don't have any order.

```
listOfSources.remove( ((TreeSet) listOfSources).last() );
```

Comment: This is bad practice. See why in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540347/2873507

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative you can set listOfSources as a SortedSet

```
SortedSet<String> listOfSources = new TreeSet<String>();
```

Then you can use `last()` method without casting to TreeSet

```
listOfSources.remove(listOfSources.last());
```

I think that this is a preferred approach since you suppose that your Set has an order.

Answer (score 3):

For TreeSet you can use `pollLast` function.

```
listOfSources.pollLast();
```

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#pollLast()

Comment: For this to work one would need to declare the variable as a `NavigableSet`

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient is to use `NavigableSet`'s [`pollLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#pollLast()) method.

For best practice, you should declare your variable as a `NavigableSet` instead as a `Set`.

```java
NavigableSet<String> listOfSources = new TreeSet<String>();

// ...

listOfSources.pollLast();
```

It is better than casting your variable to a `TreeSet` for several reasons:

- You should keep the choice of the implementation in only one place. If you cast to `TreeSet` as has been advised in other answers, and you later change the chosen implementation at the place where you define your variable but forget to change it below, it will throw an exception
- Essentially the fact that your logic requires you to remove the last element means that the behavior you expect from your variable is that of a `NavigableSet`, not just of a `Set`. Thus the choice of that variable's type should make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use Stack class. (Although less efficient for the problem in question)

```
     Set<String> listOfSources = new TreeSet<String>();

     Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
     stack.addAll(listOfSources);
     ...
     String lastElement = stack.pop();
```

`pop()` method will get the last element and remove it from the stack.

Comment: This would be less efficient (as you're creating a shallow copy of the collection, and then sorting it) and redundant - as the sorted structure is already in place, just needs accessing properly.

Comment: It's just for reference by other users that have similar problems. Maybe the Stack can be a option in other cases. In this one this is really less efficient.